# Creating new blob from older one that is stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, blob

I have basic html page where I want to upload image file, and after closing or reloading page I want that image to be there.
HTML code is :

```
<input type='file' accept="image/*">
<img alt="your image" height=400 width=auto>
```

Javascript code:

```
let img = document.querySelector('img'); 

document.body.onload = () => {
    if(localStorage.image){
        let source = JSON.parse(localStorage.image)
        let file =  new File([source], 'download.jpg', {type: 'image/jpeg', lastModified: Date.now()})
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    }
}

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
    localStorage.image = JSON.stringify(img.src)
});
```

My questions are:

1. When I `console.log(localStorage.image)`, after uploading and reloading page, I will get one blob, and because from security reasons I can't use same blob, I tried to make new File and then from that file to create blob that I can later use, but when I console.log new blob (`conosle.log(img.src)`) I received different blob, so my question is why that happened, is there a way to correct that, I see that these two  files has different `file.size` but when I want to change that it stays same
2. Also is there a second way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't persist blob objects between sessions (the blob URL will expire), you need to use a serializable format such as a data URL. Using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) you can read the image file straight to a data url, and this can be stored in localStorage.

```js
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', function() {
  img.src = fileReader.result;
  storage['image'] = fileReader.result;
})

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files.length > 0) {
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Here is a pen where I modified your code to use FileReader and data URLs (had to use sessionStorage because of codepen but localStorage should work)

https://codepen.io/Douile/pen/gOwORea?editors=1011